# How to reduce a repetitive javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, duplicates

i'm a Javascript beginner and now i have something too complex for me to solve.
I will have to write this code block HUNDREDS of time, and the only difference will be in these 3 variables, which would change for every code duplicate.

fkbtn01,
reak00,
buttonf01.

Is there a way to solve this?...Thank you.

JS:

```
//  START OF REPETITIVE CODING BLOCK
$(document).ready(function(){
    var distanza = $('.fkbtn01');

    $('.reak00').on('focus', function(){
    var posizione = $(this).val(); 
    distanza.css({left:posizione}).animate({
      'left': (posizione *100 / 200)
    });
  });

       $('.reak00').on('change', function(){
    var posizione = $(this).val(); 
    distanza.css({left:posizione}).animate({
      'left': (posizione *100 / 200)
    });
  }); 

     $('.reak00').on('focus', function(){
        r = $('#reak00').val().toString(16);
        var opacityRed = r / 100;        
        $("#buttonf01").css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,255," + opacityRed + ")");
        $("#buttonf01").css("box-shadow", "0 0 25px rgba(255,127,50," + opacityRed + ")");

    });
  });
    $('.reak00').on('change', function(){
        r = $('#reak00').val().toString(16);
        var opacityRed = r / 100;        
        $("#buttonf01").css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,255," + opacityRed + ")");
        $("#buttonf01").css("box-shadow", "0 0 25px rgba(255,127,50," + opacityRed + ")");

    });
//  END OF REPETITIVE CODING BLOCK
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnhope/0sfempxr/4/)

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes an hour, two at the most, and it gives you all kinds of useful information -- including the answer to this question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign all of your code into a single function:

```
    var assignHandlers = function(selectorOne, selectorTwo, selectorThree){
        return function(){

            var distanza = $(selectorOne);
            $(selectorTwo).on('focus change', function(){
                var posizione = $(this).val(); 
                distanza.css({left:posizione}).animate({
                  'left': (posizione *100 / 200)
                });
            });


            $(selectorTwo).on('focus change', function(){
                    r = $(selectorTwo).val().toString(16);
                    var opacityRed = r / 100;        
                    $( selectorThree ).css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,255," + opacityRed + ")");
                    $( selectorThree ).css("box-shadow", "0 0 25px rgba(255,127,50," + opacityRed + ")");

            });
        };
      };
```

Then use it  with the 'changeable factors' as many times as is wanted:

```
    $(document).ready( assignHandlers('.fkbtn01', '.reak00', "#buttonf01") );
    $(document).ready( assignHandlers('.fkbtn02', '.reak00', "#buttonf01") );
    $(document).ready( assignHandlers('.fkbtn03', '.reak00', "#buttonf01") );
    $(document).ready( assignHandlers('.fkbtn04', '.reak00', "#buttonf01") );
    ....
```

Comment: You should put that line right after the code above it, and both these in place of your 'repetitive block', where that line needs to be repeated for all your "fkbtn--" selectors, instead of the entire block.

Comment: From your code i see that you don't use selectorOne. i tried on my page and without it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Edited it: yes I had missed it when I did some edit. 'SelectorOne' is your distanza div selector. It is added now.

Comment: It almost work. Now something weird happens. When i use more instances, only the last one works the way it should, the issue is in the distance calculations. Please give a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/johnhope/ybzhshtn/1/

Comment: If I remove loadSettings and saveSettings, it shows up fine, except the upper two have shorter lengths to begin with and don't overlap the grey box. For this I changed a CSS rule: .fkbtn01, .fkbtn02, .fkbtn03 input to .fkbtn01 input, .fkbtn02 input, .fkbtn03 input.  See https://jsfiddle.net/camhb38u/.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. You can hook *multiple* events with a single call to [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

   ```
   $('.reak00').on('focus change', ...
   ```
2. You can do more than one thing in an event handler
3. You can set multiple styles on an element by passing an object to [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

So for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var distanza = $('.fkbtn01');

    $('.reak00').on('focus change', function() {
        //           ^^^^^^^^^^^^--------- two events
        // The first thing
        var posizione = $(this).val();
        distanza.css({
            left: posizione
        }).animate({
            'left': (posizione * 100 / 200)
        });

        // The second thing
        var r = $('#reak00').val().toString(16);
        var opacityRed = r / 100;
        $("#buttonf01").css({ // <==== Object for multiple styles
            "background-color": "rgba(255,255,255," + opacityRed + ")",
            "box-shadow": "0 0 25px rgba(255,127,50," + opacityRed + ")"
        });
    });
});
```

---

Side note: Your second `change` handler was actually outside your `ready` callback, but your indentation was incorrect and so that wasn't obvious. I've assumed above it was meant to be inside with the others.

Comment: @JohnIntj, what variables? Element selectors?